# php login form without database just a text file

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I have the php below that works vary vary fine on localhost apache server (WAMP server) but when i put it online withowt any reason or error it doesnt do its job ! please need an answer although i will change my hosting server i dont like their services because there are many functions disabled. (update : i have a "html code" that is the profile that this code should logon-to . the profile html is after the php . **this php has the problem that shows the die message even when the user and password is correct. this problem only on online server**)

---

```
<?php

function password($username='noneuser') {

  $tegjitha=file_get_contents("pasetkkadmin.txt");
  $infot=preg_split('/'.PHP_EOL.'/',$tegjitha,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  $final=null;
  foreach ($infot as $info) {
    $pos=preg_split('/:/',$info,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    if ($pos[0]==$username){
      $final=$pos[1];
    }

  }
  return $final;


}


function isuser($input) {
  $tegjitha=file_get_contents("pasetkkadmin.txt");
  $infot=preg_split('/'.PHP_EOL.'/',$tegjitha,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  $rezultati=false;
  foreach ($infot as $info) {
    $pos=preg_split('/:/',$info,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ($input==md5('albipatozi'.$pos[0])) { $rezultati=true;}

  }
  return $rezultati;
}


if  ( isset($_GET['dil'])  ) {
  setcookie('mbajmend','',time()-3600*24*365);
  die('<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=index.php" />');

}

if  ( isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) ) {
  $username=$_POST['username'];

} else {$username=null;}

if  ( isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) ) {
  $passwd=sha1('justastring£"'.$_POST['pass']);


} else {$passwd='none';}

if  ( isset($_POST['mbajmend']) && !empty($_POST['mbajmend']) ) {
  $koha=time()+3600*24*60;
} else {$koha=null;}

$duhet=password($username);
if ($passwd==$duhet) { 


  setcookie('mbajmend',md5('sdaggs'.$username),$koha);


} elseif (!( isset($_COOKIE['mbajmend']) && isuser($_COOKIE['mbajmend'])  )) {


  setcookie('mbajmend','',time()-3600*24*360);
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) &&     (preg_match('/[index.php]$/',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ||     preg_match('/[admin\/]$/',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ) { $textshtes='Perdoruesi ose     Fjalkalimi jane Gabim !  '; }
  else { $textshtes='Ju Lutem Vendosni Te Dhenat Thuaja'; }

die('<body style="background:lightgrey;">
<div id="trupi" style="position:relative; background:#999999; margin:auto; width:360px;     margin-top:160px; height:260px;">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" style="position:absolute;     margin:56px; text-shadow:black; font-style:oblique; color:darkred">
  <label><strong>Perdoruesi:&nbsp;</strong>
  <input type="text" name="username" />
   </label>
  <p>
   <label><strong>Fjalekalimi:</strong>
   <input type="password" name="pass" />
   </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" />
    Me Mbaj Mend te Ky Kompjuter</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label style="float:right;">
    <input type="submit" value="Identifikohu"  />
    </label>
  </p>
  </form><p style="text-align:center; color:darkred; background:grey">    <b>'.$textshtes.'</b></p>
 </div>
 </body>

  ');

 } 

 ?>
<html>
this should be shown when user and passord is correct :)
</html>
```

i tried to echo every single variable one by one step by step and everything is OK exept the fact it doesnt work

the passdords txt file is pasetkkadmin.txt- 
its model is

superadmin:a3b22231bbe113a948a349af09cea4e4129584de

the first line is : superadmin and its password is : albi
whith that data it should work but it doesnt

Comment: Sifting through your code is very difficult; do you know about indentation? You can indent blocks of code to make things more readable. Also, do you get any particular error? Have you made any debugging attempts?

Comment: yes i have made but no error rezultet. (by the way the code on my pc is in blocks but here im not adapted to use the 4 spaces needed for the code so i have messed it up a little when i copy-pasted it )

Comment: "doesn[']t do its job"; "doesn[']t work" -- what _specifically_ isn't working? (We shouldn't have to ask!)

Comment: hahaha after this php code i have an html code that is the profile html . this php shows the die message everytime and i dont get the profile html showd. :D nice anotation by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local you use WAMP(it's windows), but online the server usually runs on a Linux-system.

The difference is, that PHP_EOL has different values on Windows(CR+LF) and Linux(LF), so your pasetkkadmin.txt will not work like expected with the used PHP-code when you create it on windows and upload it onto a linux-server.

Example pasetkkadmin.txt

```
foo:bar[CR][LF]
foo2:bar2
```

On windows, splitted by PHP_EOL(`[CR][LF]`) it will be:

```
array(0=>foo:bar,
      1=>foo2:bar2)
```

On linux, splitted by PHP_EOL(`[LF]`) it will be:

```
array(0=>foo:bar[CR],
      1=>foo2:bar2)
```

Comment: but the string returned from the code password is identical to the password and the problem with my code stays to this point : $duhet=password($username);
if ($passwd==$duhet) { // put the cookie } . even $passwd is identically to $duhet the server doesnt return true the statement ($passwd==$duhet) !! can you explain this ?! because im getting really bored by this code . (so it isnt a OS diference problem)

Comment: wehe ! you had right i just tested it and all i had to do was to trim that string in some way and that solved my case. Im vary vary thankful.